# Expected value - deck of cards problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Can you tell me if I have solved this correctly?

If we take a random card from a deck and then put the card back in the deck, and then shuffle it, and repeat this $x$ times, what is the expected number of cards that have been drawn at least one time?

---

So I know the probability of drawing a card is $1$ out of $52$, hence the probability of not drawing a card is $1 - \tfrac{1}{52}$.

If the process is repeated $x$ times then the probability is $\left( 1 - \tfrac{1}{52} \right)^x = \left( \tfrac{51}{52} \right)^x$.

The probability of drawing a card at least one time is $1 - \left(\tfrac{51}{52} \right)^x$.

The expected value is then $52 \left( 1 - \left( \tfrac{51}{52} \right)^x \right)$.

Comment: Yeah, looks perfectly fine to me, but I would add more explanations if this is a homework assignment. You first use negation rule, then the independence of shuffles, the negation rule again, and finally the linearity of expectation (it is true even though the variables involved are dependent). Note that I also edited your question to change $k$ to $x$ to make the notation consistent.

Comment: thanks!  Revision accepted

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that is the way to go.  **Indicator Random Variables, and the Linearity of Expectation**.

There are 52 cards in the deck.  The probability of drawing a particular card (say card $i$) at least once is $(1-(51/52)^x)$.

So if $X_i$ is the indicator random variable for this event (ie: takes on value 1 when the event occurs, but 0 otherwise), then as this is a Bernoulli random variable, its expectation is the probability for the event: $$\mathsf E(X_i)=(1-(51/52)^x)$$

Which is the identical for all fifty two indicator random variables.

The count of cards that appear at least once is $\sum_{i=1}^{52}X_i$, so by the Linearity if Expectation:$$\mathsf E\left(\sum_{i-1}^{52}X_i\right)=52\,(1-(51/52)^x)$$.

Comment: If you repeat 52 times, the expectation is around 33.